# How do I look for a number following a substring in a string with no spaces

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to SQL and am trying to look for all instances in a column named `Countries` in a table, where the substring "`number=`" is followed by a number in a string such as "`fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=0.9hdk*nf&`".

I can find all instances with the substring "`number`", with the following

```
SELECT COUNT (Countries)
FROM NameOfTable
WHERE Countries LIKE '%number=%';
```

but how do I only count the instances where `number=` is followed by a number and I exclude instances, such as "`fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=hdk*nf&`"?

Edit:

```
where countries rlike '.*number=[0-9]+.*'
```

did the trick. I have upvoted it. Thank you!

Comment: Is the column `varchar` or `nvarchar`? Do you know what the column's `COLLATION` is?

Comment: Assuming it's `nvarchar` with default (`Latin1...`) collation, this should do it: `WHERE ( Countries LIKE N'%number=[0-9.]%' ) OR ( Countries LIKE N'%number=[0-9.][0-9.]%' ) OR ( Countries LIKE N'%number=[0-9.][0-9.][0-9.]%' )` - you'll need to repeat the `OR ( ... )` part for each digit or `.` char you expect to find (T-SQL doesn't support real regular-expressions yet, y'see).

Comment: @Dai - Just curious... Why did you assume `SQL Server`?

Comment: What is your SQL database?

Comment: @PM77-1 The lack of backticks in a beginner's code is proof (to me, at least) that they aren't targeting MySQL. If they were using Postgres then they'd probably first reach for its Regex features. That leaves Oracle and MSSQL as the likely contenders, but exposure to Oracle by beginners is limited, so chances are it's MSSQL.

Comment: I'm working in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Snowflake, you can use `rlike`. The reason `%number=[0-9]%` doesn't work with Snowflake is because allowing character class `[]` inside a like expression is a database specific feature supported by some (SQL Server for example) but not all databases.

```
where countries rlike '.*number=[0-9]+.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PATINDEX, I've popped an example so you can see the start position.

```
DECLARE @Countries TABLE(Country NVARCHAR(100)) 
INSERT INTO @Countries SELECT 'fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=0.9hdk*nf&' 
INSERT INTO @Countries SELECT 'fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=hdk*nf&'

SELECT *,PATINDEX('%number=[0-9]%',Country) FROM @Countries

SELECT COUNT(Country) FROM @Countries WHERE PATINDEX('%number=[0-9]%',Country)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing just a small piece in your current code. Something like below may help you out.

```
SELECT COUNT (Countries)
FROM NameOfTable
where Countries LIKE '%number=[0-9]%';
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I tried originally before posting but for some reason Snowflake doesn't yield results. If I do this  '.*number=[0-9]+.*', as suggested by Kathmandude, it works.

Answer (score 0):

so really the same answer as Kathmandude, plus some more context.

Using a CTE to fake the data:

```
with NameOfTable(countries) as (
    select * from values
        ('fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=0.9hdk*nf&'),
        ('fhfsehnslwoeh%_number=hdk*nf&')
)
select count(countries)
from nameoftable
where countries RLIKE '.*number=[0-9].*';
```

we see that we can use [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike), which much like LIKE needs wild cards added to it, but given it uses REGEXP syntax, it needs to be `.*` not `%`

[image]

you can also use REGEXP_LIKE which is an alias:

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(countries, '.*number=[0-9].*');
```

or REGEXP if you like the inline style of RLIKE but want to me more explicit it is a REGEXP:

```
where countries REGEXP '.*number=[0-9].*';
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is very useful, thank you! Would you happen to know why this works but "where Countries LIKE '%number=[0-9]%'; " does not?

Comment: LIKE only supports single or multiple token wild matches https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like#usage-notes the square bracket notation is regexp grammar.